# Reopen STDERR/STDOUT to write to combined logfile with timestamps

Tags: perl

I basically want to reopen STDERR/STDOUT so they write to one logfile with both the stream and the timestamp included on every line. So `print STDERR "Hello World"` prints `STDERR: 20130215123456: Hello World`. I don't want to rewrite all my print statements into function calls, also some of the output will be coming from external processes via `system()` calls anyway which I won't be able to rewrite.

I also need for the output to be placed in the file "live", i.e. not only written when the process completes.

*(p.s. I'm not asking particularly for details of how to generate timestamps, just how to redirect to a file and prepend a string)*

I've worked out the following code, but it's messy:

```
my $mode = ">>";
my $file = "outerr.txt";
open(STDOUT, "|-", qq(perl -e 'open(FILE, "$mode", "$file"); while (<>) { print FILE "STDOUT: \$\_"; }'));
open(STDERR, "|-", qq(perl -e 'open(FILE, "$mode", "$file"); while (<>) { print FILE "STDERR: \$\_"; }'));
```

*(The above doesn't add dates, but that should be trivial to add)*

I'm looking for a cleaner solution, one that doesn't require quoting perl code and passing it on the command line, or at least module that hides some of the complexity. Looking at the code for [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Capture-Tiny-0.21/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm) it doesn't look like it can handle writing a part of output, though I'm not sure about that. `annotate-output` only works on an external command sadly, I need this to work on both external commands and ordinary perl printing.

Comment: I don't know if this might be of help. [how to send both STDOUT and STERR to the same file](http://perlmonks.com/?node=579419).

Comment: I can do that already, but don't know how to add the timestamps and stream description.

Comment: I have no idea how Capture::Tiny works. Looks like it might. Why didn't you just try it?

Comment: Tried it, I don't think it does the job I'm looking for, unless I'm not using it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The child launched via `system` doesn't write to `STDOUT` because it does not have access to variables in your program. Therefore, means having code run on a Perl file handle write (e.g. `tie`) won't work.

Write another script that runs your script with STDOUT and STDERR replaced with pipes. Read from those pipes and print out the modified output. I suggest using IPC::Run to do this, because it'll save you from using `select`. You can get away without it if you combine STDOUT and STDERR in one stream.